# Countif or sumif function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have 2 tables, one which gets populated with results (on the right) and the other is the summary of that results table (on the left).  Not even sure if countif is the correct approach but I just wondered if there was a formula I can put into B2:D3 which can add up the number of occurences in the results table.  So going forward I'll just need to manually insert another row in columns I and J which would update B2:D3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as shown in image below, going forward when you add more values in column `I` & `J`, it shall give you the number of occurrences of `L`, `W`, & `D` respectively as per Name

Enter the formula in cell `B2` & `Fill Down` -- `Fill Right`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A2=$I$1:$J$1)*(B$1=$I:$J))
```

What this formula does is creates an array of TRUE's & FALSE's, select the `Array 1` & `Press F9`,

```
($A2=$I$1:$J$1) {TRUE,FALSE}
```

likewise for the `Array 2` as well

```
(B$1=$I:$J) {FALSE,FALSE;TRUE,TRUE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,)
```

Each `Array 1` will be multiplied by corresponding `Array 2` and returns the sum of the products, by far this is safest option and can be used in all Excel Versions.

[image: NUMBER OF OCCURRENCES]

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, although it is quite slow.  Never used SUMPRODUCT before is it not very performant?

Comment: @tommyhmt yeah bit of but to make it fast what you can do is change the ranges into `TABLE` by pressing `CTRL T` or from `INSERT TAB` select Table, now apply the formula, it wont take much time here, since when you use a formula in Table Structure it automatically fills for the rest of the cells and is pretty quick, however there is a draw back for `TABLE` as well, when the data is quite large, but it will work perfectly in your case.

Comment: @tommyhmt well you can do one more thing, instead of using all the rows, just use absolute reference since, `SUMPRODUCT` Function is quite fast rather than other function, just tested the same, So use this way `=SUMPRODUCT(($A2=$I$1:$J$1)*(B$1=$I$2:$J$3))` and you can also, change the range `$I$1:$J$3` into a table to make it more dynamic, !

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up, but I'm now getting "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated.
At the moment there are 63 people and 54 results, pretty sure it's the number of people which is causing the issue rather than the number of results

Comment: @tommyhmt no issues, can you share me a one drive link of your workbook. So that I can help you with a solution

Comment: yeah of course, I can just send the whole file on email to be fair it's not that big, what's your email address?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following formula into B2:

```
=COUNTIF($H$2:$H$3,B$1)
```

- It will count all 'W' occurrences in the H2:H3 range. You can drag this formula to the right.
- For the B3 cell, you need to update the column from H to I.